# How to find any information in elasticsearch result

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I use the python in order to integrate Elasticsearch into my programme.
I use pycurl and I manage to add, modify and delete any documents, but now i would like to test if one document exist. I wrote a short code who send a get request, but I not manage to find all the information than i want, because i've got this error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find'

my short code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                        
import re
import pycurl
import json
import StringIO
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

retentionDays = 30

c = pycurl.Curl()
b = StringIO.StringIO()

c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/twitter/tweet/_search?q=reference:24272605AAA')
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.perform()

try:
    decoded = json.loads(b.getvalue())

    # pretty printing of json-formatted string                                                                                                           
    print json.dumps(decoded, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    var = decoded['hits']
    print "JSON parsing example: ", decoded['hits']
    print  var.find(':0, ')

except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError):
    print "JSON format error"
```

if someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update with more detailed error log.

Comment: what info are you looking for? Also dict's have a get method but no find method. So `var.get("total")` would return 0 which is the value

Comment: No worries, you're welcome, using get is like using var["total"] to access a value except it won't throw a key error if it does not exist, by default it returns None but you can pass it you own value if you want like var.get("total","No key") etc..